# How to represent xml in json if xml contains duplicate(more than one) tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert XML to java using library
[x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/) and [xml2json](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/xml2json.js)

When I convert I am not able maintain the order

Here is my XML:

```
<OBJECT name="myobject">
  <popup manager="mymanager">
    <Item>
        <m>P</m>
    </Item>
    <menu id="admin">
        <Text></Text>
        <m>S</m>
        <Item id="UnLocked">
            <m>U</m>
        </Item>
    </menu>
    <Item id="separator"></Item>
</popup></OBJECT>
```

When I convert the tags becoming 
Array of Items and when I recreate XML from JSON

```
<OBJECT name="myobject">
<popup manager="mymanager">
    <Item>
        <m>P</m>
    </Item>
    <Item id="separator"></Item>
    <menu id="admin">
        <Text></Text>
        <m>S</m>
        <Item id="UnLocked">
            <m>U</m>
        </Item>
    </menu>
</popup></OBJECT>
```

The Item Tag becoming Array and `<Item id="separator"></Item>` going up.

How can we solve this?

here is the plunker : [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6duuYoC7DOz9bcGN5sbQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot automatically translate such a structure to JSON, for the reasons you have discovered. I would encode it similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "myobject",
  "popup": {
    "manager": "mymanager",
    "items": [
      {
        "m": "P"
      },
      {
        "id": "admin",
        "type": "menu",
        "item": {
          "id": "UnLocked",
          "m": "P"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "separator"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: But when you re convert this to XML will it remains same?

Comment: Not if you convert automatically, no. You would need to make a conversion procedure, in both directions - neither works automatically.